# Remove rows with same content but with different order

Tags: powerbi, data-analysis

I have a query in Power BI that represents relationships between entities. The relation is non directional. I want to remove the redundant relationships but I have no idea how.
This is an example of my data:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| a | b |
| c | f |
| b | a |
| g | j |

I want to remove the third row with the B - A because A - B is already present. Do you have any ideas how I can do this?

cheers,
Jo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Add a custom column:
  `List.Sort({[col1],[col2]})`
- Select that column and Remove Duplicate rows